# Запросы к модели django

Tags: python, django

Мне необходимо взять все данные из модели и осуществить проверку. Если переменная id не совпадает со значением в поле user_id в модели то необходимо выполнять return render(request, 'index/telegram.html')
Код:

```
 id = request.GET["id"]
 user_id = users.objects.get(user_id=id)
 if(user_id != ""):
      phonenumber = user_id.phonenumber
      request.session['phonenumber'] = phonenumber
 else:
      return render(request, 'index/telegram.html')
```

В таком случае выдаётся ошибка если user_id!=id, а мне надо создать проверку на совпадение переменной id со значениями в поле модели user_id

Comment: какая ошибка выдается?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первая проблема - `users.objects.get(user_id=id)`. Должно быть так `User.objects.get(user_id=id)`, если вы используете стандартную таблицу пользователей django.

Далее функция `get` возвращает объект пользователя, если такой существует в БД. Если же объекта с таким идентификатором не существует, то функция бросает исключение. Вам его нужно обработать.

Еще одно некритичное замечание: `get` возвращает объект пользователя, поэтому переменную лучше назвать `user`, а не `user_id`.

Итого имеем:

```
id = request.GET["id"]
try:
    user = User.objects.get(user_id=id)
    phonenumber = user.phonenumber
    request.session['phonenumber'] = phonenumber
except User.DoesNotExist:
    return render(request, 'index/telegram.html')
```

Comment: Получаю ошибку Object of type DeferredAttribute is not JSON serializable. Предполагаю, что на возникает при добавлении сесии. Как можно решить?

Comment: Это нужно задать другой вопрос и там описать подробности.